# JSONB to Array Data Type

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I currently have a table sessions with a column actions(JSONB).

I am able to properly store an array from my frontend to my database using `array_to_jsonb(array value)`.

**The structure of my array (array value) looks like this:**

```
var arrayStructure = [
    {name: 'email client', check: false},
    {name: 'send contract', check: false}
]
```

Unlike a lot of the questions I've seen on SO about modifying JSONB or accessing certain keys, I am only interested in converting the entire JSONB data back to an array for the frontend.

My temporary fix is to map through the array and use JSON.parse() in Javascript to restructure each object in the array. I cannot use JSON.parse() on the entire array, as it throws an error.

I'm looking for a query to bring back the array format to the JSONB data type stored. I've seen JSONB_SET, LATERAL, AND JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT. But not in a way that worked to bring back a proper array.

**Starts As:** JSONB in actions column in table named sessions

**Should Result In:** A query that brings back all rows, but with the actions column (JSONB) converted back to an array for the frontend:

```
select session_id, session_name, someFunction or lateral here(actions) from sessions
```

[Screenshot of Sessions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjohE.png)

I've tried queries like this:

```
SELECT 
   session_id, 
   actions::jsonb -> 'name' as name
FROM sessions;
```

And receive back null for name. I've tried ->> to access a deeper level, but that didn't work either.

This is half of the correct query result:

```
select session_id, jsonb_array_elements_text(actions)
from sessions
group by session_id;
```

Which results in this (only pay attention to results for session_id of 264):
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybjSU.png)

Now I have objects in their own rows as:

```
 {"name": "some task", "check": "false}
```

When what I want for the actions column is:

```
[ {name: "some task", check: false}, {name: "other task", check: true} ]
```

So I need to further parse the JSON and group by session_id. I'm just struggling to build a sub-query that does that.

**Steps to Create Set Up:**

```
create table fakeSessions (
session_id serial primary key, 
name varchar(20), 
list jsonb
)

insert into fakeSessions(name, list)
VALUES(
'running',
'["{\"name\":\"inquired\",\"check\":false}", "{\"name\":\"sent online guide\",\"check\":false}", "{\"name\":\"booked!\",\"check\":false}"]'
)

insert into fakeSessions(name, list)
VALUES(
'snowboarding',
'["{\"name\":\"rental\",\"check\":false}", "{\"name\":\"booked ski passes\",\"check\":false}", "{\"name\":\"survey\",\"check\":false}"]'
)
```

**The closest query I've created:**

```
with exports as (
    select jsonb_array_elements_text(actions)::jsonb as doc from sessions
)
select array_agg(doc) from
exports, sessions
group by session_id;
```

Get the text values, and then apply an aggregate function to those returned rows. Just can't get the select array_agg(doc) to work as expected. Most likely because I need a different function in that place.

Comment: Please provide some ddl / dml to reproduce the issue. Also, show your expected output and format

Comment: Please show how the table and the data looks like. Do you have one single row with the whole jsonb array? Do you have one row per array element? Do you have single columns for name and check?

Comment: @S-Man, The actions column is JSONB that holds an array of objects. Within each object are 2 keys: name and check. [ {name: 'some name' check: false} ]

Comment: @KaushikNayak, I have attached a screenshot of sample data to help. There is no issue or error message. I'm just unable to find in the DOCS a way to use postgres to convert back to an array without using JSON.parse() on the frontend.

Comment: I really still don't understand it. Please add a some sample data (as text so that we can copy into our tools) and your expected output. what I understood is: you have some rows with an array and you want do merge these arrays. so row1 has [{name:a, check:t}, {name:b, check:f}] and row 2 has [{name:c, check:t}] and you want [{name:a...}, {name:b,...}, {name:c,...}]?

Comment: @S-Man, I apologize for not being clear enough :/ I added queries to build a sample table with the data I'm working with. Yes, you are correct in my expected output!

Comment: Thanks for your sample data. Now we need the expected output for these data :) Does my answer help? If not please add this output :)

Answer (score 5):

Does this help?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=300002af854a3417f1e9b690194e1871)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(elem) 
FROM
    sessions, jsonb_array_elements(actions) as elem
```

1. `jsonb_array_elements()` expands the `jsonb` array into one row each `jsonb` element
2. `jsonb_agg()` aggregates these `jsonb` elements into one big array.

Comment: You rock! I was able to get the correct format by building off of this. Thank you for the amazing feedback and working through this with me. Made my day :)

Comment: I just now earned the ability to upvote with this question/answer. So I'm excited to give my first upvote! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reach the answer by building off of your query! Thank you so much. The query that got the expected outcome was this:

```
with exports as (
    select session_id, jsonb_array_elements_text(actions)::jsonb as doc from sessions
)
select session_id, jsonb_agg(doc) from exports
group by session_id;
```

I wasn't using the jsonb_agg() function once I got the elements. The difference for getting the exact format was just using `jsonb_array_elements_text::jsonb`

Comment: Hm json_array_element_text converts the json elements into pure text. and after that you're converting it back to json. That doesn't seem logical. The json engine of postgres is highly performant. If you cast the objects to othet types inbetween you might lose much performance.